# Code runs in Mathematica 10.4 but doesn't in Mathematica 11: plotting and labeling

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, labeling

I am having a very strange problem. I made a very long code in Mathematica 10.4, the same notebook is not running properly in version 11. I figured out few problems myself.My code has an automatic way of labeling the plot. It used to work fine but now it shows Rowbox[.... etc in the plot. I am not able to understand what had happened in the new versions that creates that problem. Please guide me in this.
Following is the command I use to create frame label.

```
parametersNV := HoldForm[Sequence[R = 2.5, α = 1.5, Pr = 4.5, Subscript[θ, w] = 1.8, Rd = 0.2]]; ReleaseHold[parametersNV];
```

this is needed for input to the label 
the command for label is

```
framelbl := {{"θ(ζ)",Rotate["", 180 Degree]}, {"ζ", StringReplace[ToString[parametersNV, StandardForm],"HoldForm[" | "]" -> ""]}}
```

The difference between he outputs in versions 10.4 and 11 is shown in the picture below
[image]
Please guide me to get rid of this error.

A simplified test code is as follows. I had to cut down a lot of things so it may not look very elegant, sorry for that.

```
Remove["Global`*"];
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], CellEpilog :> SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Next, Cell]]
styleoptn = List[List[Black, Dashing[None], Thickness[0.005]],{Black, Dashing[Small], Thickness[0.005]},{Black, Dashing[Medium], Thickness[0.005]},{Black, Dashing[Large], Thickness[0.005]}];
xlb := -1;
xub := 1;
numcurves := 4;
parametersNV := HoldForm[Sequence[R = 2.5, Rd = 1.2,Subscript[θ, w] = 1.8]]; ReleaseHold[parametersNV];
framelbl := {{"θ(ζ)",Rotate["", 180 Degree]}, {"ζ", StringReplace[ToString[parametersNV, StandardForm],"HoldForm[" | "]" -> ""]}}
paramterV := {A};       
parvarying := List[0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3];
parvaryingname := {"A= ``"}
curves := Evaluate@Table[d[i], {i, 1, numcurves}]
ftns := Table[v[parvarying[[i]], x], {i, 1, numcurves}];
v[A_, x_] := x^4 + A  x^3 + 3 Rd x^2 + 5  Subscript[θ, w]
Table[d[i] := Evaluate[ ftns[[i]]], {i, 1, numcurves}];
imgsz = 400;
plotleg := {Placed[
LineLegend[Automatic, 
 Table[Style[
   StringReplace[
    ToString@
     NumberForm[StringForm[parvaryingname[[1]], parvarying[[i]]], 
      ExponentFunction -> (Null &)], 
    RegularExpression["\\.$"] -> ".0"], "Arial", 12], {i, 1, 
   numcurves}], LegendLayout -> "Column", 
 LegendFunction -> "Frame", LegendMarkerSize -> {{30, 3}}], {0.7, 
 0.6}]};
Plot[{curves[[1]], curves[[2]], curves[[3]], curves[[4]]}, {x, xlb,xub}, PlotStyle -> styleoptn, ImageSize -> imgsz, Frame -> True,Axes -> False,FrameLabel -> framelbl, RotateLabel -> True,LabelStyle -> Black,PlotLegends -> plotleg,FrameStyle -> Directive["Arial", 16]]
```

I again apologize for the ugly look of the code; I dont know how to split it in to cells here.
The code works perfectly fine in 10.0.2. I just copy-pasted the above code in a new notebook.
Please see the screenshot
[image]

@Mr.Wizard!
The output is as follows

```
"\!\(\*RowBox[{\"HoldForm\", \"[\", RowBox[{RowBox[{\"R\", \"=\", \"2.5`\"}], \",\", RowBox[{\"Rd\", \"=\", \"1.2`\"}], \",\",RowBox[{SubscriptBox[\"\[Theta]\", \"w\"], \"=\", \\"1.8`\"}]}], \"]\"}]\)"
```

Comment: Would you kindly post your program that automatically labels the plot, along with a sample plot that uses it?  Thanks.

Comment: it is posted now

Comment: Can you use `parametersNV := "R=2.5,Rd=1.2,\*SubscriptBox[\[Theta],w]=1.8"` instead of what you have?

Comment: I need their values too. For label they are supposed to behave like strings but for calculations we do need their values. And these values are supposed to be typed only once.

Comment: Naveed and @Szabolcs, I found that *Mathematica* 10.3, 10.4 and 11 generate the `RowBox` structures instead of the intended label.  You have to go as far back as *Mathematica* 9 to see it rendered properly.

Comment: The code works perfectly fine in 10.0.2. i am attaching a screenshot aslo

Comment: Your code also works on my system, 10.1.0 under Windows.  Please include in your question the exact output of `InputForm[ ToString[parametersNV, StandardForm] ]` in *Mathematica* 11.

Comment: It seems to me that your problems stem from using `Sequence` to hold the parameter definitions. This results in multiple arguments to `HoldForm` - which it is not supposed to have. How about using `Row` instead of `Sequence`?

Comment: I tired Row. It shows the label but enclosed in Row[...]

Comment: But Row in its correct syntax wasn't working so I used Row[{item1,item2... }] without { }. i.e, I used them as a single item.for { } it even more messed up than sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
parametersNV = HoldForm[{R = 2.5, α = 1.5, Pr = 4.5, Subscript[θ, w] = 1.8, Rd = 0.2}];
ReleaseHold[parametersNV];

framelbl = {{"θ(ζ)", Rotate["", 180 Degree]}, {"ζ", Row[Thread@parametersNV, ","]}};

Graphics[{}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> framelbl, LabelStyle -> 14]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It works perfectly fine for the moment :). Thank you everyone for your efforts and help.