# Enclosing text of Row in quotes

Tags: plotting, string-manipulation, labeling, row

For a particular purpose I need to achieve the following:
Can we convert

```
Row[R = 2.5, Rd = 1.2, Subscript[\[Theta], w] = 1.8]
```

into

```
"R = 2.5, Rd = 1.2, Subscript[\[Theta], w] = 1.8]"
```

programmatically? I will use that for labeling the graphs.
This question is a continuation of my previous question
[Please see the Previous question here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/124766/code-runs-in-mathematica-10-4-but-doesnt-in-mathematica-11-plotting-and-labeli)

The result is supposed to be of this type
[image]

Comment: Is your `Row` syntax wrong intentionally?

Comment: Row would be used to define the values of the parameter with their names. It will execute the values that shall be used during the numerical computations;at the end while labeling the graphs, the text inside Row[ ] is going to be used as a frame label.Both the names and the values

Comment: @naveed You have written `Row[item1, item2, item3]` instead of `Row[{item1, item2, item3}]`, your version is syntactically incorrect and Kuba asks if this is intentional? Or do you really have it in the syntactically correct form?

Comment: yes its intentional otherwise it wont execute the values. I previously used Sequence[] but now its making problems in version 11. please see the the previous question (link given above) to clarify the situation. I am sorry for this confusion.

Comment: parametersNVlbl := "R=2.5, Rd=1.2, \*SubscriptBox[\[Theta],w]=1.8"
or can you suggest the way to remove these quoted from parametersNVlbl to make it executable? for that i will delete this question and ask a new one